# Современная валидация email

Tags: php, email, kohana

Немного отстал от современных тенденций, и возник вопрос по валидации email. Я так понимаю, проверять по старинке регуляркой уже не катит. Хотелось бы узнать, как грамотно сегодня проверить правильность адреса на клиенте и на сервере. Возможно, уже есть какие-то встроенные инструменты...
На сервере kohana 3.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда `filter_var` только появился, он не пропускал мой емайл типа "test_@ya.ru". Сейчас вроде поправили (у меня php 5.5):

```
var_dump(filter_var("test_@ya.ru", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
exit(-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Кто вам сказал, что по регулярке не катит? Это, наверное, самый надежный способ. Вы можете запретить в регулярке все, что необходимо. Вот самая полная для емейлов http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html , но не знаю, работает ли она с кириллическими доменами.

Также есть и другой способ, [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-var.php), но в действии я его не проверял. Говорят, что работает нормально.

Answer (score 0):

В kohana 3 есть класс Validation. В гугле же полно инфы по kohana.